# Windows 7 Search in Start Menu

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

At my home, I cannot search for program in the Start Menu, neither search for `services.msc` or `regedit` in the Start Menu Search Bar. Every time I have

```
No item match your search.
```

When I go to the Control Panel, in Indexing Option. I have removed everything except my Start Menu and the System32 folder.

What do I have to do to make it works? At my job, all works fine but not at home...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you've just been too selective with your folders.

regedit is in your Windows I think rather than System32, so I think that's why it's not working. services.msc should be in %SYSTEMROOT%\System32 so not sure why that's not working. As a test, you could index the whole drive (or at least from %WINDIR% down.

Comment: But why the Start Menu application does not work?

Comment: The Start menu just has short cuts in it, not the applications themselves.

Comment: i know but the start menu folder contain links... i cannot even get them